# PHP forum database optimisation

Tags: php, sql, database, optimization, forum

I've been thinking about creating a forum in PHP so I did a little research to see what the standard is for the tables that people create in the database. On most websites I've looked up, they always choose to have one table for the threads and a second for the posts on the threads.

Having a table for the threads seems perfectly rational to me, but one table to hold all the posts on all the threads seems like a little too much. Would it be better to create a table for each thread that will hold that thread's posts instead sticking a few hundred thousand posts in one table?

Comment: You didn't specify which database you're going to use, but most of them can easily handle tables with millions of rows. Chances are you won't have that many posts, so you'll be fine. Creating a table for each thread is NOT the way to go.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not really making a forum, t'was just a hypothetical question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tables should represent the structure of the data in your database. If you have 2 objects, which in this case are your threads and your posts, you should put them in 2 tables.

Trust me, it will be a nightmare trying to figure out the right table to show for each post if you do it the way you're thinking. What would the SQL look like? Something like

```
SELECT *
FROM PostTable17256
```

and you would have to dynamically construct this query on each request.

However, by using 1 table, you can simply get a ThreadID and pass it as a variable to your query.

```
SELECT *
FROM Posts
WHERE ThreadID = $ThreadID
```

Relational databases are designed to have tables which hold lots of rows. You would probably be surprised what DBAs consider to be a "lot" by the way.  A table with 1,000,000 rows is considered small to medium in most places.

Answer (score 1):

Nope nope nope.  Database love huge tables.  Splitting posts into multiple tables will cause many many headaches.

Answer (score 0):

Storing posts in one table is best solution.
MySQL can easily hold millions of rows in a table.

Creating multiple tables may cause few problems.
For example you will not be able to use JOIN with posts from different threads.